# Timeline from Google Charts does not recognize colors

Tags: javascript, json, google-api

I'm trying to color some bars from the timeline the color i want based on some criterias I choose in the controller. The Json that is used as data is next:

```
{
  "cols": [
    { "id": "", "label": "Project Name", "pattern": "", "role": "", "type": "string" },
    { "id": "", "label": "Period", "pattern": "", "role": "", "type": "string" },
    { "id": "", "label": "Start", "pattern": "", "role": "", "type": "date" },
    { "id": "", "label": "End", "pattern": "", "role": "", "type": "date" },
    { "id": "", "label": "", "pattern": "", "role": "style", "type": "string"}],
  "rows": [
    { "c": [{ "v": "test", "f": null},{"v": "Fesability", "f": null},{"v": 1504224000000,"f": null},{"v": 1504742400000,"f": null},{"v": "#45a128","f": null}]},
    { "c": [{ "v": "test", "f": null},{"v": "Conceptual", "f": null},{"v": 1504742400000,"f": null},{"v": 1505347200000,"f": null},{"v": "#45a128","f": null}]}]
}
```

and the script that I render in the page:

```
<script>
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['timeline'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: '/Report/RetrieveData?projectLeader=@ViewBag.ProjectLeader',
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;


        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('timeline'));

        chart.draw(data);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is it does not color the bars as I want. I have also tried with 'color: #435278', the same result, not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order matters when it comes to columns, so Google Charts will recognize the style columns only if it is the third one. I formated the json to match this and everything was ok. The new json looks like this:

```
{
  "cols": [
    { "id": "", "label": "Project Name", "pattern": "", "role": "", "type": "string" },
    { "id": "", "label": "Period", "pattern": "", "role": "", "type": "string" },
    { "id": "", "label": "", "pattern": "", "role": "style", "type": "string"}
    { "id": "", "label": "Start", "pattern": "", "role": "", "type": "date" },
    { "id": "", "label": "End", "pattern": "", "role": "", "type": "date" }],
   "rows": [
    { "c": [{ "v": "test", "f": null},{"v": "Fesability", "f": null},{"v": "#45a128","f": null},{"v": 1504224000000,"f": null},{"v": 1504742400000,"f": null}]},
    { "c": [{ "v": "test", "f": null},{"v": "Conceptual", "f": null},{"v": "#45a128","f": null},{"v": 1504742400000,"f": null},{"v": 1505347200000,"f": null}]}]
```

}